# Django queryset with extra()

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, sqlite

I have four models

```
class Group(models.Model):
    pass

class Item(models.Model):
    group = ForeignKey(Group)

class ItemRevision(models.Model):
    item = ForeignKey(Item)
    date = DateField()

class ItemRevisionMonth(models.Model):
    item_revision = ForeignKey(ItemRevision)
    year = PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    amount = IntegerField()
```

I am trying to make a quite complex sql query in Django so I don't think that Django ORM can handle it.

I need to print all groups and annotate each group with a sum of amount, `SUM(amount)`. Besides this it should only select 1 `ItemRevision` (the latest added).

I think it's something like:

```
Group.objects.all().extra(select={
    SELECT SUM(amount) FROM app_itemrevisionmonth LEFT JOIN app_itemrevision ON item_revision_id = app_itemrevision.id WHERE item_id = app_item.id AND app_item.group_id = app_group.id
})
```

but I don't know how to tell to only select from the latest revision.

## Edit 1

Maybe something like:

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount)
FROM
    app_itemrevisionmonth
LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT
          id
      FROM
          app_itemrevision
      WHERE
          date < %s
      LIMIT
          1
    )
ON
    item_revision_id = app_itemrevision.id
WHERE
    item_id = app_item.id AND
    app_item.group_id = app_group.id
```

## Edit 2

The structure will be

```
"id": 1,
"items": [
    {
        "id": 1
        "revisions": [
            {
                "id": 1, 
                "date": "01-10-2014", 
                "months": [
                    {
                        "year": 2014, 
                        "amount": "2321"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "year": 2014,  
                        "amount": "500"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "year": 2014,  
                        "amount": "500"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "year": 2014,  
                        "amount": "500"
                    }, 
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

There could be more than 1 revision for an item and in such cases it should only use the latest revision and ignore the other revisions. Besides that it should be possible to use revisions before a specific date.

Comment: I think it would not work: `WHERE
    item_id = app_item.id AND`

Answer (score 0):

Try annotation

```
Group.objects.all().annotate(
    sum=models.Sum('item_set__itemrevision_set__itemrevisionmonth_set__amount')
)
```

Details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Comment: I don't think I can use annotation as I want the ability to choose different revisions. I really need something like SUMIF :-)

But it would be perfect if I could choose revisions as `ItemRevision.objects.filter(date_lte=??).latest()` which gives the option to see what the data looked like before a specific date.

Comment: You have no `date` field in model `ItemRevision`. Could you refactor an example, pls?